# How to save a result in a file while I am reading multiple files at the same time?

Tags: matlab

I have this code , in which I want to read multiple file & find the 'percentage_of_MPRs' for each file 
This is the code that I have tried,, but the problem  that I get all "percentage_of_MPRs" having the value of the last iteration! 
note that the value of aaa is changed for each iteration

```
for ff= 3:10
         file_name= fullfile(sprintf('node%d.txt',ff));
        A= importdata(file_name); 

    ******* code*****

    aaa=  [CH_con, MPRf{S,D}];%%% check 

         aaa2= unique(aaa);
         number_of_MPRs= length(aaa2);
         percentage_of_MPRs(ff) =   (number_of_MPRs/n)*100


    end
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the snippet you provide.

Comment: I do not understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to answer your question:

You get the same results for all elements in `percentage_of_MPRs` because `unique(aaa)` is equal in all loops, thus `aaa2` is equal, thus `number_of_MPRs/n` is constant.

Maybe you want:

```
%% Insert missing code here:
%
%

for ff = 3:10
   %% Insert more missing code here 
   % 
   %

   aaa2 = unique(aaa(ff));
   number_of_MPRs = length(aaa2);
   percentage_of_MPRs(ff) =   (number_of_MPRs/n)*100
end
```

Note that the code above is *very very* bad, but it's the best I can do with the information in the question.

Comment: but the problem is aaa is a vector so when I put aaa2 = unique(aaa(ff))  , I got this error ((In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.))

Comment: It wasn't a "copy-paste-this-code" kind of answer, but more like: see if you can do anything along these lines. Does `aaa` change inside the loop? Can you supply the entire code (if it's not too long). As a rule of thumb, (unless the question is particularly good), if people need to scroll in order to read the code, then it's most likely too long for people to bother.

Comment: each file from the files that I want to read will generate different value of aaa.

Comment: You should probably have included that in the question. Have you tried the debugger? Insert breakpoints and see what value each variable is at each iteration.